# Receiving more bytes than sent C++

Tags: c++, sockets, send, shutdown, recv

I want to send a file from a Linux server to a Windows client through sockets, the problem is that I receive more bytes than I send.

Server code----------------------------------------------

```
if (resultEnviarLongitud = send(ClientSocket,GotFileSize.c_str(),1024,0)<0){
    cout<<endl<<"Error mandando la longitud! "<<endl;
}
rewind(fs);

while ((len = fread(Buffer,1,1024, fs)) > 0)
{
    if((resultEnviar = send(ClientSocket,Buffer,1024,0)) < 0){
        printf("ERROR: Failed to send file %s.\n", nombreArchivoADescargar.c_str());
        break;
    }
    sumEnviada+=len;
}

send(ClientSocket,"Hi",sizeof(Buffer),0);


cout<<"Bytes enviados: "<<sumEnviada<<endl;
strcpy(data, "");

cout<<endl<<"ARCHIVO MANDADO EXITOSAMENTE!"<<endl;
rutaArchivoADescargar.clear();
```

Client code-----------------------------------------

```
if (resultRecibirLongitud = recv(sock, Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), 0) > 0)
{
    LongitudArchivo = atoi(Buffer);
    cout<<endl<<"Longitud Archivo a Recibir: " <<LongitudArchivo<<endl; 
}

FILE *fp=fopen("imagen.jpg","wb");
if (fp==NULL){
    cout<<"Error al crear archivo."<<endl;
}else{
    bzero(Buffer2, 1024); 
    int fr_block_sz = 0;
    int contador=0;

    //shutdown(sock, SD_SEND); I HAVE TO USE IT?

    while((fr_block_sz = recv(sock, Buffer2, 1024, 0)) >= 0) 
    {
        if (fr_block_sz == 0) break;
        if ( strcmp (Buffer,"Hi") == 0) break;
        int write_sz = fwrite(Buffer2, 1, 1024, fp);
        if(write_sz < fr_block_sz)
        {
            printf("File write failed on server.\n");
        }
        bzero(Buffer2, 1024);
        contador+=fr_block_sz;
        if (contador >= LongitudArchivo)break;
        bzero(Buffer2, 1024); 
    }
    cout<<endl<<"Numero de bytes recibidos: "<<contador<<endl<<endl;
    if(fr_block_sz < 0)
    {
        printf("Error receiving file from client to server.\n");
    }
    printf("Ok received from client!\n");
    fclose(fp); 
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: what did you send and what did you received?

Comment: I send an 1348656 bytes image and I receive 1349632 bytes
If I use "shutdown(sock, SD_SEND);" the image looks like the Server file but it have a bigger size.
If i don't use "shutdown(sock, SD_SEND);" the image seems corrupted.

Comment: hahahaha... Answer me.

Comment: Note, that you should use shutdown to ensure that the bytes sent are actually received. Shutdown(send) only returns successfully if all bytes were received. send/close do not guarantee that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while ((len = fread(Buffer,1,1024, fs)) > 0)
{
    if((resultEnviar = send(ClientSocket,Buffer,1024,0)) < 0)
```

One of your issues is that you always send 1024 bytes of the buffer even if you `fread` fewer bytes. (Note that 1348656 rounded up to the nearest multiple of 1024 is 1349632.)

So, on the write side you want something like:

```
while ((len = fread(Buffer,1,1024, fs)) > 0)
{
    if((resultEnviar = send(ClientSocket,Buffer,len,0)) < 0)
```

and on the read side you want something like:

```
while((fr_block_sz = recv(sock, Buffer2, 1024, 0)) >= 0) 
{
    // ...
    int write_sz = fwrite(Buffer2, 1, fr_block_sz, fp);
```

Your initial `send` is also problematic as you always send 1024 bytes with no check that this is the actual length of what is returned by `c_str`.

Comment: Any idea of how can I check the length of Buffer? Because if I do sizeof(Buffer) it returns me 1024...

Comment: @user2824788: It's not about the length of the buffer, it's the number of bytes read that is important and you already store that in `len`.

Comment: But I can't send 'len' bytes because the receiver doesn't know 'len'.
I've been thinking about, once the file is downloaded, calculate the number of 'garbage' bytes and delete them. What do you think about that?

Comment: @user2824788: The receiver can check the number of bytes that it received (that the sender sent), from the return value of `recv` but only if you pass the correct value to `send` from the sending side.